# Jquery mmenu multiple instances

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances, mmenu

I need to implement to instances of mmenus using menus. The first works fine (it is amazing) and it is positioned on the left side but I am not able to add the second one opening from the right side.

I need to add a second icon menu, hopefully customized, on the fixed top bar and use it to open the second menu. But as soon as I add the code for second menu, the first one stops to work because the icon menu (on the eft side) opens the second menu
Here below some code. The id of the left menu is #menu and the id of the right menu is #listPanel

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#menu"></a>
        Event Name 2  - Race Name
        <a href="#listPanel"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="mapContainer">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer ">
        Real-time News
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>  Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  Map</a></li>                  
            <li><a href="athList.html"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>  Lista Atleti</a></li>
            <li><a href="liveTracking.html"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>  Live Tracking</a></li>
            <li><a href="stops.html"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  Intermedi</a></li>
            <li><a href="performance.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  Prestazioni</a></li>
            <li><a href="rank.html"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>  Classifica MySdam</a></li>
            <li id="sponsorMenu"><img src="images/sponsor/LogoSM.png" alt="MySdam" width='90%'></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav id="listPanel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>  Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</div>
```

While the query code is

```
$(function() {
    $("#menu").mmenu({         
        "offCanvas": {
          "zposition": "front"
       },
       "header": {
          "title": "Menu",
          "add": true,
          "update": true
       },
        "footer": {
          "add": true,
          "title": "Smartrack @ 2014"
       }
    });

    $("#listPanel").mmenu({
       "offCanvas": {
          "zposition": "front",
          "position": "right"
       }
    });  
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yhta5ux7/)

I really searched a lot for a solution in the mmenu site and in stack overflow but i did not find any solution.
Where am I wrong??

Thanks for the support

Comment: Fiddle updated to fix missing HTML (my mistake). Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yhta5ux7/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. If it's just a matter of having the menus open, you could arrange your HTML as such:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#menu">Menu Left</a>
        <a href="#listPanel">Menu Right</a>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="../index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>  Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>  Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="listPanel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>  Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This adds another nav element, puts some text in the anchor elements, and works as expected in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2pe4gzy/). I sincerely hope this was what you were looking for :).

Comment: I added the fiddle, and my original version lacked the HTML for one of the menus. That may have created some confusion. As you said, though, it works despite what the OP states.

Comment: Yes thanks, for sure it helped. I get a partial solution, that is I was able to have to separte menus.What I need now is to have two separate menu icon, the standard one on the left side and the second on the right side of header bar. Implementing this solution I get overlapped ICons `<a href="#menu"></a>
    Event Name 2  - Race Name
    <a href="#listPanel"><span id="panelButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>` . Where I am wrong? Thanks again for precious support

Comment: I'm sorry, I simply don't understand what you mean. Could you make a jsfiddle to describe your problem with code?

Comment: Thanks, I solved. It was my mistake. The problem was related on positioning of the 2 Menu Icon. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Giovanni, if my answer was useful and solved your problem, you should click on the checkmark to accept it :).